# how can i add "point" before the last two numbers

Tags: php

How can I add a point before the last two numbers?

Lets say numbers is

```
299 , 250 , 400 , 4500 , 20099
```

I want to get last two digit and add point befor it

i.e

```
2.99 , 2.50 , 45.00 , 200.99
```

using php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the function [substr-replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr-replace.php)

```
substr_replace('299','.',-2,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have I missed something or wouldn't this do it - from php.net - the manual.

```
 $number = 1234.5678;

 // english notation without thousands separator
 $english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
 // 1234.57
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Substring_replace is the simpler option as per version by @Roadirsh, which would do what is really asked for. Sean's version will also work as per comment by @sean `number_format($number/100, 2, '.', '');` (included here in case comments get deleted). My version will only handle numbers with existing decimal points or add .00

Although expected behaviour was that numbers would be rounded, further testing shows that they are not rounded if they are already only two places of decimals as in the `/100` part. They are rounded if more decimal places are present.

I would have deleted my version but it might be of use to have here.

Comment: that would just append `.00`, instead of changing `299` to `2.99` see https://3v4l.org/aEl9L. It would work if you did `number_format($number/100, 2, '.', '')`

Answer (score 1):

How about using [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php)?

```
<?php
$numbers = explode(' , ', '299 , 250 , 400 , 4500 , 20099');
$numbersHandled = array_map(function($e) {
    return number_format($e/100, 2, '.', '');
}, $numbers);

print_r($numbersHandled);
```

Check [runnable](http://code.runnable.com/VlEkyJ43ma0kDvyd/how-can-i-add-%E2%80%9Cpoint%E2%80%9D-before-the-last-two-numbers-for-php).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex.

```
echo preg_replace('/(\d+)(\d{2})/', '$1.$2', '299 , 250 , 400 , 4500 , 20099');
```

Output:

```
2.99 , 2.50 , 4.00 , 45.00 , 200.99
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hY1zM6/1